# Start batch after restart

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch start after a restart. Will this work? 
This `doupdate.bat` is stored at a USB drive and is going to be used in many computers.

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /V 1 /D "%~d0\cmd\DoUpdate.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want it start on startup? Since you cant use Autorun.inf since that needs to be manually clicked to start it up and ever since Win7 it doesnt allow you to change what file it opens on USB, it sounds like your only option is the startup folder. You could write a second batch script to copy the file into the computers startup folder. Here is the code to copy the file into the startup folder as a bat:

```
C:
copy doupdate.bat "C:\Users\%USERNMAE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\doupdate.bat"
```

(Note: Thats assuming the bat to move the file is on the USB, and also replace the 'C:' in the code with whatever drive it will be moving to, you cant simply have it move directly to the C drive or CD to it, you have the enter the name since interacting between different drives on batch it tricky, so you have to cd to them a special way first)

But that would only have the file auto-open on restart only on the user that you were currently using when you ran the file.

Also that method requires you to have the file installed to the users computer.

And if you dont want the file to stay on the users computer after its already done its job, simply add this code at the end of "doupdate.bat" for it to delete itself:

```
del "C:\Users\%USERNMAE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\doupdate.bat"
```

its as simple as that, that way when it gets run from the Startup folder, as soon as its done with all of its purpose, it will remove itself, and then to re-add it, simply re-run the bat to move the file.

I hope my info helped, and if any of the methods here wont work for your specific bat file just tell me and ill try to find a different method to do it and will edit this post to include that method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
copy "doupdate.bat" "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Note: Make sure to use this in Windows 10. I am not sure if this will work in Windows 8, 7 but it should also work